# Android camera preview rendered to a texture is stretched

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, camera

I'm sending android camera preview to Unity3d using texture and it is stretched. The preview is not rendered to any view in android but directly to a texture with:

```
setPreviewTexture(texture);
```

Then, the bytes are sent to Unity3d and drawn on screen with every onPreviewFrame.

The camera preview size and the texture size are set to 1024x768 and the texture container in Unity3d has the same size. The device's resolution is 960x540 so it's a different ratio. I'm selecting a supported resolution for the camera, the native size has a ratio of 4:3 so there should be no stretching.
It seems as if android is rendering to texture only the part that can actually be rendered to screen - it takes a 16:9 image and renders it to a 4:3 texture.
If I'm wrong please correct me but that how it seems to work in this example.
Here is a bit of code:

```
public int startCamera(int idx, int width, int height) {
    nativeTexturePointer = createExternalTexture();
    texture = new SurfaceTexture(nativeTexturePointer);

    mCamera = Camera.open(idx);
    setupCamera(width, height);

    try {
        mCamera.setPreviewTexture(texture);
        mCamera.setPreviewCallback(this);
        mCamera.startPreview();
        Log.i("Unity", "JAVA: camera started");
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        Log.w("Unity", "JAVA: CAM LAUNCH FAILED");
    }
    return nativeTexturePointer;
}

public void stopCamera() {
    mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
    mCamera.stopPreview();
    mCamera.release();
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, 0);
    Log.i("Unity", "JAVA: Camera stopped");
}

private int createExternalTexture() {
    int[] textureIdContainer = new int[1];
    GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textureIdContainer, 0);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, textureIdContainer[0]);
    return textureIdContainer[0];
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private void setupCamera(int width, int height) {
    Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
    params.setRecordingHint(true);
    params.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO);
    params.setPreviewFormat(17);
    params.setZoom(0);
        // 16 ~ NV16 ~ YCbCr
        // 17 ~ NV21 ~ YCbCr ~ DEFAULT *
        // 4  ~ RGB_565
        // 256~ JPEG
        // 20 ~ YUY2 ~ YcbCr ...
        // 842094169 ~ YV12 ~ 4:2:0 YCrCb comprised of WXH Y plane, W/2xH/2 Cr & Cb. see documentation *
    params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
    Camera.Size previewSize = getOptimalSize(width, height, mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes());
    Camera.Size picSize = getOptimalSize(width, height, mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPictureSizes());

    params.setPictureSize(picSize.width, picSize.height);
    params.setPreviewSize(previewSize.width, previewSize.height);
    params.setWhiteBalance(Camera.Parameters.WHITE_BALANCE_AUTO);
    params.setExposureCompensation(0);

    try{
        mCamera.setParameters(params);
    } catch (Exception e){
        Log.i("Unity", "ERROR: " + e.getMessage());
    }

    Camera.Size mCameraPreviewSize = params.getPreviewSize();
    prevWidth = mCameraPreviewSize.width;
    prevHeight = mCameraPreviewSize.height;

    int[] fpsRange = new int[2];
    params.getPreviewFpsRange(fpsRange);
}

private Camera.Size getOptimalSize(int width, int height, List<Camera.Size> sizes) {
    if(mCamera == null)
        return null;

    final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.1;
    double targetRatio=(double)width / height;

    if (sizes == null)
        return null;

    Camera.Size optimalSize = null;
    double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
    int targetWidth = width;

    for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
        double ratio = (double) size.width / size.height;
        Log.i("Unity", "RES: size=" + size.width + "/" + size.height + "/ Aspect Ratio: " + ratio + "target width: " + width + "target height: " + height);

        if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE) continue;
        if (Math.abs(size.width - targetWidth) < minDiff) {
            optimalSize = size;
            minDiff = Math.abs(size.width - targetWidth);
        }
    }

    if (optimalSize == null) {
        minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
            if (Math.abs(size.width - targetWidth) < minDiff) {
                optimalSize = size;
                minDiff = Math.abs(size.width - targetWidth);
            }
        }
    }
    Log.i("Unity", "optimal size=" + optimalSize.width + "/" + optimalSize.height + "/ Aspect Ratio: " + (double) optimalSize.width / optimalSize.height);
    return optimalSize;
}

public int getPreviewSizeWidth() {
    return prevWidth;
}

public int getPreviewSizeHeight() { return prevHeight; }

public byte[] bytes;
@Override
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    bytes = data;

    //Log.i("Unity", "JAVA: " + Integer.toString(data.length));
    UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage(gameObjectTargetName, "GetBuffer", "");
}
```

It is required that the texture sent to Unity3d is 1024x768 without cropping. Does anyone have any fix for that?

**UPDATE(added C# code)**

This code gets preview from java:

```
void CreateCameraTexture() {
    _texWidth = nativeCameraObject.Call<int>("getPreviewSizeWidth");
    _texHeight = nativeCameraObject.Call<int>("getPreviewSizeHeight");
    _cameraPreview = new Texture2D(_texWidth, _texHeight, TextureFormat.Alpha8, false);
    _converter = new YUVDecode(_texWidth, _texHeight);
    shaderMat.SetFloat("_Width", _texWidth);

    if (OnCameraTextureCreated != null)
        OnCameraTextureCreated(_cameraPreview);
}

private byte[] _bytes;
public void GetBuffer(string str) {
    _bytes = nativeCameraObject.Get<byte[]>("bytes");
    SetColor(_bytes);
    _cameraPreview.LoadRawTextureData(_bytes);
    _cameraPreview.Apply();

    UpdateLibFrame();
}

void SetColor(byte[] bytes) {
    _converter.SetBytes(bytes);
    shaderMat.SetTexture("_YUVTex", _converter.yuvtexture);
}

void UpdateLibFrame() {
    if (OnFrameUpdate != null) OnFrameUpdate(_cameraPreview.GetRawTextureData());
}
```

This code in another class shows the data:

```
private RectTransform previewRect {
    get {
        if (!_previewRect)
            _previewRect = cameraPreview.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
        return _previewRect;
    }
}

private void GetPreviewFromCamera() {
    NativeCamera.OnCameraTextureCreated += (Texture2D cameraTex) => {
        if (cameraPreview != null && cameraPreview.texture != null)
            DestroyImmediate(cameraPreview.texture);

        previewRect.sizeDelta = new Vector2(1024, 768);

        cameraPreview.texture = cameraTex;
        cameraPreview.enabled = true;
    };
}
```

**UPDATE: Added link to a sample project**

The project is here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/wid1qa9cmq3ck6w/CameraPreview.zip?dl=0

CameraJava is a gradle project. The output is a .AAR file that you have to copy to Assets/Plugins.

Comment: where is the unity code?

Comment: I have updated the post with C# code

Comment: i couldn't replicate your code completly, texture2d stays black on unity. maybe because i use YUY2 format? that would explain your shader code. any chance you can upload the full code?

Comment: make sure you set the orientation of the Camera. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35490789/picture-taken-from-camera-displayed-in-imageview-is-always-horizontal-android/35491306#35491306 for determining the right setting.

Comment: @andruido I will try to make an example project that replicates this.

Comment: @Endre Börcsök setDisplayOrientation makes sense when you use setPreviewDisplay. Anyway the preview is not rotated.

Answer (score 0):

sorry for the delay. i finally had time to test your project. it looks fine to me. here is what you can do in Unity to get a good result (though only tested for landscape, since you haven't implemented rotation handling in android it seems): go to player settings and set default orientation to **landscape left**. set the Canvas Scaler to the same reference resolution as your camera image (1024x768). finally set Z rotation of RawImage to 0. due to the 4:3 ratio, top and bottom will be cut but that's normal. if you want the full image, set the cavas scaler to match height instead of width.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm afraid you didn't understand what the problem is and I don't blame you because I might have had trouble explaining it properly. The problem is that the bytes received from Android are stretched. I have tried saving the bytes to a file to prove my point and the images were indeed stretched. No problem on Unity side here.

Comment: if i compare the fix, i applied describing above, with the image from a camera app with the same resolution, i get the exact same image. no visual stretching there.

Comment: Like I said, the problem is not on Unity side for me, I save the bytes as a JPG file and the image is stretched. Anyway, I might close the topic because I have decided to use Camera2 API and the problem disappeared.

Comment: then the problem was in how you saved the image because the preview is fine. yeah, better use camera2, though it's still should be possible with camera1 if you want support older devices, too.

Comment: Can you post pics?

Comment: sure. [here](https://imgur.com/W9uDxuz) is a screenshot of the preview in Open Camera with resolution 1024 x 768 and [there](https://imgur.com/jtyQGUg) is a screenshot with of the camera preview in Unity3D with same resolution.
finally you can compare them [here](https://imgur.com/a/TJxfs) one above the other.

Comment: Thanks. I did exactly what you said in your response. I changed the orientation, set the Canvas Scaler. And to prove that I'm not crazy here is the link to the screenshot made by my phone: https://www.dropbox.com/s/dx4ifxmlrp6dj5i/Screenshot_20171115-130702.png?dl=0